# How to make in-grid image to take available height

Tags: html, css

I try to arrange grid in my page. Each grid item is consist of image and text below the image.
The grid item itself  is flex (`flex-direction: column`). I want the image to take the available height, and the text to take the min height.

```css
.main {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 120px);
  grid-gap: 16px;
}
.main__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #a0a0a0;
}
.main__item:hover {
  border-color: #000;
}
.main__item--1 {
  grid-column: 1/span 1;
  grid-row: 1/span 1;
}
.main__item--2 {
  grid-column: 2/span 1;
  grid-row: 1/span 1;
}
.main__item--3 {
  grid-column: 3/span 1;
  grid-row: 1/span 3;
}
.main__item--4 {
  grid-column: 1/span 2;
  grid-row: 2/span 2;
}
.main__item--5 {
  grid-column: 1/span 2;
  grid-row: 4/span 2;
}
.main__item--6 {
  grid-column: 3/span 1;
  grid-row: 4/span 2;
}
.main .categoryImage {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.main .categoryText {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
    <div class="main__item main__item--1">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOMGUmxNPK-k7H6O9rScZDBulnrROW5zf_vA&usqp=CAU"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">Jeans</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main__item main__item--2">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYRs43ip3txPtxH2gVOlvnmrI--WPqkh8QHg&usqp=CAU"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">T-Shirts</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main__item main__item--3">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScoxDRfLwKyD5ThC8mRC76lByyjWhQKUu4VQ&usqp=CAU"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">Hats</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main__item main__item--4">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://tbsnews.net/sites/default/files/styles/big_2/public/images/2020/04/11/gentleman-man-accessories-sunglasses-wallpaper-preview.jpg?itok=xbyIOxlm&timestamp=1586590381"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">Accessories</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main__item main__item--5">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://asset20.ckassets.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2019/12/Jackets-on-Club-factory.jpg"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">Jackets</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main__item main__item--6">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://preview.redd.it/9ofx5enj3cw41.jpg?auto=webp&s=8a7996fd197a475a24d98405e09ea9bfa1928d47"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">Shorts</a>
    </div>
</main>
```

So basically  I want the text to be in the very bottom, and the image to take the available space. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to CSS:

```
.main__item img {
   flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `flex-grow: 1` to your `.categoryImage`:

```
.main .categoryImage {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

> This property specifies how much of the remaining space in the flex container should be assigned to the item (the flex grow factor).

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow#description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)

*I also removed `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);` from your example as this caused the content to outgrow its container (`.main__item`) on larger screen sizes.*

Full example:

```css
.main {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 16px;
}
.main__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #a0a0a0;
}
.main__item:hover {
  border-color: #000;
}
.main__item--1 {
  grid-column: 1/span 1;
  grid-row: 1/span 1;
}
.main__item--2 {
  grid-column: 2/span 1;
  grid-row: 1/span 1;
}
.main__item--3 {
  grid-column: 3/span 1;
  grid-row: 1/span 3;
}
.main__item--4 {
  grid-column: 1/span 2;
  grid-row: 2/span 2;
}
.main__item--5 {
  grid-column: 1/span 2;
  grid-row: 4/span 2;
}
.main__item--6 {
  grid-column: 3/span 1;
  grid-row: 4/span 2;
}
.main .categoryImage {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.main .categoryText {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
    <div class="main__item main__item--1">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOMGUmxNPK-k7H6O9rScZDBulnrROW5zf_vA&usqp=CAU"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">Jeans</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main__item main__item--2">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYRs43ip3txPtxH2gVOlvnmrI--WPqkh8QHg&usqp=CAU"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">T-Shirts</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main__item main__item--3">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScoxDRfLwKyD5ThC8mRC76lByyjWhQKUu4VQ&usqp=CAU"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">Hats</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main__item main__item--4">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://tbsnews.net/sites/default/files/styles/big_2/public/images/2020/04/11/gentleman-man-accessories-sunglasses-wallpaper-preview.jpg?itok=xbyIOxlm&timestamp=1586590381"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">Accessories</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main__item main__item--5">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://asset20.ckassets.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2019/12/Jackets-on-Club-factory.jpg"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">Jackets</a>
    </div>
    <div class="main__item main__item--6">
        <img class="categoryImage"
            src="https://preview.redd.it/9ofx5enj3cw41.jpg?auto=webp&s=8a7996fd197a475a24d98405e09ea9bfa1928d47"
            alt="item">
        <a class="categoryText" href="/">Shorts</a>
    </div>
</main>
```